# iphone + cookies

Tags: mobile, iphone

Does iphone support cookies????

Answer (score 4):

iPhone is simply a piece of hardware so, no it doesn't support cookies. It's the built-in Safari web browser which supports cookies.

Answer (score 3):

Look  at: [NSHTTPCookie](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookie_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSHTTPCookieStorage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[URL Loading System Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/URLOverview.html) says:

> The NSHTTPCookie class encapsulates a
>   cookie, providing accessors for many
>   of the common cookie attributes. It
>   also provides methods to convert HTTP
>   cookie headers to NSHTTPCookie
>   instances and convert an NSHTTPCookie
>   instance to headers suitable for use
>   with an NSURLRequest. The URL loading
>   system automatically sends any stored
>   cookies appropriate for an
>   NSURLRequest. unless the request
>   specifies not to send cookies.
>   Likewise, cookies returned in an
>   NSURLResponse are accepted in
>   accordance with the current cookie
>   acceptance policy.
>
> The NSHTTPCookieStorage class provides
>   the interface for managing the
>   collection of NSHTTPCookie objects
>   shared by all applications.

- [Get cookies using iPhone SDK](http://iphonesdksnippets.com/post/2009/05/14/Get-cookies-using-iPhone-SDK.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Any modern browser can't survive without supporting cookies